# How to generate an image using NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, dynamic-image-generation

I'm using the Nextjs app router for a web app I'm working on, and I want to make a button that when clicked, generates an image (based on a couple of parameters) and then downloads it to the user's computer. How do I generate an image in Nextjs? I saw something about an [ImageResponse](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/image-response) on the NextJs docs, however, there is almost no documentation on what it actually is or how to use it.